# Why do the RPMs slightly jumpy at lower speeds?

Tags: rpm, saturn

I have a 2004 Saturn Vue with the a 3.5L V6 that the RPMs slightly jumps between 20 to 60 MPH. Though if I place the vehicle on cruise anything over 50 MPH the RPMs stay steady (still very slight jumping occurs with cruise around 20 - 40 MPH). The car runs great and I just got it out of the shop with a full diagnostic and everything came back in really good shape. There is no jerking motion with the RPM jumps so I don’t believe it is the transmission itself. 
From the research I have done I’ve come up with a few possibilities:

- Idle Stabilisation Valve
- Throttle Issue
- Throttle Position Sensor
- Battery
- ERG Valve

Please let me know if one of these makes sense and should fix the problem or if you can think of any other issues.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are the RPMs of the engine actually jumping (you can feel or hear it) or is this only seen on the tachometer?

Comment: Thank you! And yes you can feel and hear it. It is usually very minor though (usually only jumps around 100 to 300 RPMs). With cruise on it barley jumps more than 50 RPMs (under 50 MPH) constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your possibilities list is very good! I would eliminate the battery from the list.

I would check your EGR valve (a lot of times these just need to be cleaned or you can go to a junkyard and grab another to replace) and then your throttle position sensor first and foremost.

I'm currently working on a 2004 Saturn Vue chasing a "fuel vapor" issue. I replaced the EGR as part of the process because it was so covered in deposits.

Comment: Okay, is that normal for the EGR Valve to only effect the vehicle at lower speeds?

Comment: @JTMLIONS11 Did this answer fix your problem?

Comment: @JTMLIONS11 it really depends on the vehicle.  I had an 87 Mazda that it only affected it at idle and the dumb service light on the dashboard.  I cleaned it and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Throttle body : it could very dirty : check your air filter and MAS sensor but DONOT USE Throttlebody cleaner on the mass air sensor: only mass air cleaner.

Comment: Okay, I will give this a shot today. Thank you all so much!!